# Recursive function to API returning duplicate records

Tags: php

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting duplicate records when calling this recursive function.

The data is returned with keys to give the total records in the database (recsindb) and the total records returned in this call (recsonpage).  I've written a class to query the API better ($this->site), and can add parameters to the request such as getting the page number and records per page:

- $this->site->add('page-no', $page);
- $this->site->add('no-of-records', 10);

```
public function syncTransactions($page = 1, $int = 0, $return = [])
{
    $this->site->add('page-no', $page);
    $this->site->add('no-of-records', 10);
    $result = $this->site->getData($this->site->api() . 'transactions/search.json', TRUE);
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $return[$int]['transid'] = $data['customer_transaction.transid'];
            $return[$int]['description'] = $data['customer_transaction.description'];
            $return[$int]['sellingcurrencysymbol'] = $data['customer_transaction.description'];
            $return[$int]['customerid'] = $data['customer_transaction.customerid'];
            $return[$int]['sellingamount'] = $data['customer_transaction.sellingamount'];
            $return[$int]['type'] = $data['customer_transaction.type'];
            $return[$int]['key'] = $data['customer_transaction.key'];
            $return[$int]['transactiondate'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $data['customer_transaction.transactiondate']);
        }
        $int++;
    }
    
    if (
        ($result['recsindb'] >= ($result['recsonpage'] * $page)) &&
        ($result['recsonpage'] != 0)
    ) {
        $this->syncTransactions($page + 1, $int + 1, $return);
    }
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($return, TRUE) . "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting all the records duplicated when you fetch each page, or just a few overlaps?

Comment: If the data in the API changes between calls, there can be overlap between pages. You can see something similar when you page through the list of SO questions, because questions are added at the front of the list between requests.

Comment: The element that was #10 during the first call can become #11 when you fetch the second page if a new element was inserted at the front.

Comment: @Barmar $return[$int] is incremented in the recursion. $this->syncTransactions($page + 1, $int + 1, $return);

Comment: And why use recursion instead of a loop?

Comment: I'm looping through the $result array and then appending to the $return array.  It doesn't need to increment in the loop.

Comment: RE: why use recursion instead of a loop.... because I can't pull all the records in one request as there's a per page limit.  For example, if I have 5000 records and I can only pull 100 records per page, I have to use recursion to pull 50 pages of 100 records each.  And I only know I have 5000 records because of the recsindb result key.

Comment: That's not a reason to use recursion, it's a reason to use an extra loop, such as a [do-while loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php). Most people find loops easier to follow than recursion, so switching may make your problem either more obvious, or simply go away.

Comment: How does your `Site::add()` method work? What does it do if the parameter already exists, does it replace it or leave the old value?

Comment: The site:add() method at its core just adds key/value pairs to the API URL. Having a class method to do this also allows me to have multiple keys with different values, when it would otherwise be difficult to use arrays that have their keys overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this but maybe you should try to set the values before calling the function.

Like this

```
$page++;
$int++;
$this->syncTransactions($page, $int, $return);
```

But again, i'm not so sure that this is the problem.

**EDIT**

I think i found it.
Try this change

```
public function syncTransactions($page = 1, $int = 0, $return = [])
{
    $this->site->add('page-no', $page);
    $this->site->add('no-of-records', 10);
    $result = $this->site->getData($this->site->api() . 'transactions/search.json', TRUE);
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $return[$int]['transid'] = $data['customer_transaction.transid'];
            $return[$int]['description'] = $data['customer_transaction.description'];
            $return[$int]['sellingcurrencysymbol'] = $data['customer_transaction.description'];
            $return[$int]['customerid'] = $data['customer_transaction.customerid'];
            $return[$int]['sellingamount'] = $data['customer_transaction.sellingamount'];
            $return[$int]['type'] = $data['customer_transaction.type'];
            $return[$int]['key'] = $data['customer_transaction.key'];
            $return[$int]['transactiondate'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $data['customer_transaction.transactiondate']);
        }
$int++;
    }
    
    if (
        ($result['recsindb'] >= ($result['recsonpage'] * $page)) &&
        ($result['recsonpage'] != 0)
    ) {
        return $this->syncTransactions( ($page + 1), ($int + 1), $return);
    }
    return $return;
}

// Suppose that you initiated the object
print_r($obj->syncTransactions());
```

The change is the `return $this->syncTransactions` instead of just calling the function. With that you can achieve a unified object of data without repeating the same structure +1 every time.

Comment: That can't possibly make a difference, and the way he's doing it is a normal way to do recursion.

Comment: What did you change in the edit? If it's the parentheses around `$page + 1`, that also won't make a difference.

Comment: @Barmar That is true. I edited the answer

Comment: Don't just say "try this", explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar No. The real change is that i return the $return in each iteration. I tried a simplified way of the method and it seems to work

Comment: You're right, that's the problem. He's printing the partial results during each recursive step.

Comment: Add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @VeteranSlayer, that did it.